# how to clear local storage when browser close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, session-storage

I am using onload function in javascript but problem is that if browser is refresh then also clear local storage .
I want to only clear local storage when browser close not refresh browser

Comment: Why not use `sessionStorage` instead, which is discarded when the browser is closed?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, if token session is stored on `sessionStorage` you should to perform login process if you want to open some app link in another tab. Ex: on an ERP you have loaded a `Bill` on browse and do you want to open related `provider` on another tab. If you use session storage, new tab doesn't know the token. If you use local storage, new tab is opened with requested data, but, even you close the browser, the token remains (maybe a problem with shared computers) Exists a trade-off approach?

Answer (score 3):

sessionStorage will be cleared when the browser is closed... otherwise you could do a window unload listener and clear it - but this will also clear the page if the browser navigates to another page

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
   localStorage.clear();
}, false);
```

Comment: in this function execute browser refresh than also clear local storage

Comment: My problem is I don't want to clear local storage when browser is refresh.

Comment: Then localstorage isn't what you're looking for either. Your best bet is to use your browsers sessionstorage instead.